# Create a list of C# Funcs with different parameter types

Tags: c#, generics, func

I want to be able to create multiple `Func`s each of which takes in an instance of a type and returns the same type e.g.:

```
Func<Foo, Foo>
Func<Bar, Bar>
```

And then add these to a `List` (or perhaps to a `Dictionary`, keyed by the type that the `Func` handles).

Then given any instance `y` (the type of which is not known *at compile time*), I want to retrieve and invoke the `Func` that will work for on `y`.

Is what I am asking for even possible?

Comment: The closest you can get (and I have used this in the past) is something like `Dictionary<(Type source, Type destination), Delegate>`. You should wrap that up in a class that handles the type checking and casting to a proper `Func<TIn, TOut>`

Comment: I re-read and realise that you would need a different key, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of delegates. Use the type as key.

```
Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _dictionary = new();
```

And we will need a method to add delegates:

```
bool Add<T>(Func<T, T> func)
{
    return _dictionary.TryAdd(typeof(T), func);
}
```

And one to call them:

```
static T DoIt<T>(T t)
{
    if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var func))
    {
        return ((Func<T, T>)func).Invoke(t);
    }
   
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Working example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _dictionary = new();
    
    public static void Main()
    {      
        Add<String>(InternalDoIt);
        Add<int>(InternalDoIt);
        DoIt("Hello World"); // Outputs "Hello World"
        DoIt(1); // Outputs "1"
        DoIt(DateTime.Now); // Throws NotImplementException
    }
    
    static bool Add<T>(Func<T, T> func)
    {
        return _dictionary.TryAdd(typeof(T), func);
    }
    
    static T DoIt<T>(T t)
    {
        if (_dictionary.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var func))
        {
            return ((Func<T, T>)func).Invoke(t);
        }
        
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    
    static string InternalDoIt(string str){
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            return str;
    }
    static int InternalDoIt(int i) {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            return i;
    }
}
```

*No puppies or kitties died in the making of this answer.*

Comment: Yup, this is essentially how I would have done it, albeit wrapped in a nice class. And thanks for thinking of the kittens.

Comment: @DavidG Of course, I'd wrap this in a class too. I was tempted to do it for the answer. It would not be static. And there could be some other utility methods, for example to remove delegates. Edit: we could even consider if the type being registered is form a dynamically loaded assembly. Depending on the use case (and the build target), it might be worth considering if we are preventing an assembly from unloading.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the following approach?

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DoIt("Hello World");
        DoIt(1);
        DoIt(DateTime.Now);
    }
    
    static dynamic DoIt(dynamic t)
    {
        return InternalDoIt(t);
    }
    
    static object InternalDoIt(object obj) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    static string InternalDoIt(string str){
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            return str;
    }
    static int InternalDoIt(int i) {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            return i;
    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RoXK0M

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies.

Comment: @DavidG - as a cat person, it is a puppy in my case that I had to sacrifice

Comment: My point is that using `dynamic` should almost always be avoided. It is dangerous, not type-safe and horribly slow.